# How do I create blank space between rows in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am aware that in tkinter `padx` and `pady` are supposed to create padding outside of the object; and `ipady` and `ipadx` are supposed to create padding inside the object. In my case `pady` seems to also be creating padding inside an object.

The code I've used:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

input_field = Entry(screen, bd=0.5, width=25, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=13, ipadx=20)
button1 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="1", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=3)
button2 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="2", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=1, row=3)
button3 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="3", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=2, row=3)
button4 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="4", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=2)
button5 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="5", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=1, row=2)
button6 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="6", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=2, row=2)
button7 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="7", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=1)
button8 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="8", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=1, row=1)
button9 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="9", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=2, row=1)


screen.mainloop()
```

Output:

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2yQC.png)

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: When you say "solving this", what do you mean? Are you wanting more blank space between every row? Between just some rows?

Comment: @BryanOakley More blank space between every row

Comment: Have you tried using the `pady` option with the `grid` command?

Comment: I'll give that a search and try it out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pady in grid(pady = 5) and it works fine

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

input_field = Entry(screen, bd=0.5, width=25, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=13, ipadx=20)
button1 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="1", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=3, pady=5)
button2 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="2", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=1, row=3, pady=5)
button3 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="3", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=2, row=3, pady=5)
button4 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="4", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=2, pady=5)
button5 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="5", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=1, row=2, pady=5)
button6 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="6", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=2, row=2, pady=5)
button7 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="7", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=0, row=1, pady=5)
button8 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="8", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=1, row=1, pady=5)
button9 = Button(screen, bd=0.5, text="9", padx=40, pady=35, font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold')).grid(column=2, row=1, pady=5)


screen.mainloop()
```

P.S. I like to make a class for similar buttons so I don't have to write all settings again for each button